# Flushing issue with toilet

Tags: toilet

Can someone give me helpful feedback. I recently had a clogged toiled. In fact i had to take off a toilet and go in with snake and reseal the toilet back. Now my toilets flush but doesnt flush consistently. Almost every other time, water returns and fills up the bowl. To complicate the issue, i have a paralel toilet on the othe side of the wall that probably are on the same waste pipe. When water returns in the first toilet, the other toilet gets very low water level in its bowl. And if i try to flush that one as well, it gets overflow and wont flush as well..

Will be glad to get any info. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even though you snaked the line near the toilet, it sounds like the line is still blocked or slow draining such that standing water sits in the line above the point of connection to the vent.  Vent lines for toilets are often connected as shown:

[image]

Standing water above the reducing wye where the vent connects will cause water to be pulled from the toilet bowl as water flows down the line (such as when the other connected toilet is flushed).  A flood when you flush both toilets indicates the sewer line is slow draining and cannot handle that much flow.  Possibly the vent is plugged.  More likely there is an obstruction such as tree roots infiltrating the line.  If you have a septic system then it is time to pull the inspection lids, especially the one at the inlet.  Check for obstructions such soap caked near the intake baffle.

Comment: Thank you, for such a detailed response. I dont think i have a septic system. So i guess my option is to call a plumber or try to feed some chemicals down my drain((

Comment: Chris, my mistake. I do have septic system. It just hit me. I have white cap right in front of house. The question now is, do all the toilets go there? Because my basement toilet flushes well. Just trying to narrow down the issue i guess. Thanks ahead!

Comment: If you have a septic system then all sewage goes there (excluding perhaps a grey water system).  Your basement might have a holding tank and lift pump to get it up to the septic system.  Hard for me to say from here.  If you have a septic system and have not looked at it for over 5 years, then you should locate it and inspect its condition no matter what the underlying cause of your problem is.